# IOError on opening a csv file

Tags: python

I wanted to loop through a file. I can get it and I can print its location but I keep getting IOError!

```
import os, sys

directory = sys.argv[1]
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    if len(files) >= 3:
        for f in files:
            print(os.path.join(root, f))

            if f.endswith(".csv"):
                print f + " made it this far"
                with open(os.path.join(directory, f), "r") as d:
                    for line in d:
                        print "hello"
```

my readout..

```
/Users/eeamesX/work/data/GERMANY/DE_023/continuous/2015-06-01#ab6686a5-c733-4055-a15e-b28b9705b6ca/2015-06-01#ab6686a5-c733-4055-a15e-b28b9705b6ca.wav
/Users/eeamesX/work/data/GERMANY/DE_023/continuous/2015-06-01#ab6686a5-c733-4055-a15e-b28b9705b6ca/2015-06-01#ab6686a5-c733-4055-a15e-b28b9705b6ca.xml
/Users/eeamesX/work/data/GERMANY/DE_023/continuous/2015-06-01#ab6686a5-c733-4055-a15e-b28b9705b6ca/2015-06-01#ab6686a5-c733-4055-a15e-b28b9705b6ca_edited.xml
/Users/eeamesX/work/data/GERMANY/DE_023/continuous/2015-06-01#ab6686a5-c733-4055-a15e-b28b9705b6ca/foo.csv
foo.csv made it this far
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "findFiles.py", line 16, in <module>
    with open(os.path.join(directory, f), "r") as d:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/eeamesX/work/data/GERMANY/DE_023/continuous/foo.csv'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `directory` is the point from which you start traversing the filesystem. When you do `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory)`, you get the current directory as `root`, a list of the subdirectories it contains in `dirs`, and a list of the files it contains in `files`. Therefore, if you join `directory` with `f`, you will end up searching for `f` in the directory where you started your file system traversal. Such a file likely does not exist in that starting location

Rather, you want to open the file contained in the directory within which it is contained (i.e. `root`). Therefore, you should `os.path.join(root, f)` to get the correct file path